# Generic linked list inside of linked list?

Tags: java, class, oop, linked-list

I am trying to write a program which stores information about a person in a linked list. I made a simple person class to store the name, age and addresses in the list. I would also like to store multiple addresses for EACH person, and a fact about the place in another linked list, inside the person class.

So for example, "Tara" can have a home address of "10 Central Ave" and a work address of "5 Willow street" etc. The problem is, I don't know how to have a linked list inside another.

My goal is to check whether the person's name is already on the list, and if so, add another address for them. (So that there is no repeats). I am a beginner and can really use some help.

```
   public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    public LinkedList <String> adresses;

    public Person() {
        name = "default";
        age = 0;
        adresses = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public Person(String n, int a) {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public LinkedList<Adress> getAdresses() {
        return adresses;
    }

    public void setAdresses(LinkedList<Adress> adresses) {
        this.adresses = adresses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name+" "+age+" "+adresses;
    }
}

public class Adress {

    public String adress;
    public String fact;

    public Adress(String a, String f) {
        adress = a;
        fact = f;
    }

    public String getAdress() {
        return adress;
    }
    public void setAdress(String adress) {
        this.adress = adress;
    }
    public String getFact() {
        return fact;
    }
    public void setFact(String fact) {
        this.fact = fact;
    }
}
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person Tara = new Person("Tara",35);
        Person Judah = new Person("Judah",28);
        Person Mark = new Person("Mark",45);
        Person Seth = new Person("Seth",23);


        LinkedList<Object> tester = new LinkedList<>();
        tester.add(Tara);
        tester.add(Judah);
        tester.addLast(Mark);
        tester.addLast(Seth);

        System.out.println(tester);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a sanity check here, if you have an `Address` class why are you `LinkedList<String> adresses` why not `LinkedList<Address> adresses` ?

Comment: @xtratic fixed thank you

Comment: To save you from asking another question, you will also need to override equals in person and address to do what you are trying to do. The answer below will work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is about to use the next classic data structure for your project?

```
  public class Person {
    private String name
    private int age;
    public List<Address> addresses;
    //...
  }
```

Comment: I am practicing linked lists, so I prefer to use those

Comment: you can implement List<Address> as LinkedList<Address>

Comment: Please explain?

Comment: List<Address> addresses = new LinkedList<>(); https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html